# Проблема компилирования maven в javafx проекте

Tags: java, javafx, maven

В общем, при компиляции с помощью maven (mvn clean compile exec:java) выскакивает исключение + как только использую FXMLLoader :
`Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) on project libraryManagementSystem: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null`
Если его убрать из кода - всё прекрасно работает. По поводу этой ошибки глянул всё - не помогло, может мой случай какой-то отдельный. Заранее благодарю за любой фидбэк.

Main class(App)

```java
package org.example;

import ...;

public class App extends Application {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/resources/loginStage.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("just a scene");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>libraryManagementSystem</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

...

  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>run-selenium</id>
              <phase>integration-test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

Error:

```java
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) on project libraryManagementSystem: An exception occured while executing
the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Exception in Application start method: Location is required. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) on project libraryManagem
entSystem: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
```

Error -X:

```java
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) on project libraryManagementSystem: An exception occured while executing
the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Exception in Application start method: Location is required. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) on project libraryManagem
entSystem: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute (ExecJavaMojo.java:346)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:291)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1 (LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2 (LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl (FXMLLoader.java:3230)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl (FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl (FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl (FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl (FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load (FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at org.example.App.start (App.java:30)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9 (LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12 (PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10 (PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:391)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11 (PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run (InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop (Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3 (WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:832)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Возможно что-то надо добавить classpathScope в configuration, но это тоже пробовал - не выходит.

Comment: пробовали добавить com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin в <plugin/> ?

Comment: именно com.zenjava - нет, но в любом случае я решил рубануть с плеча, и постановить новую 2021 Intellj IDEA вместо 2020, переписал всё с нуля, и больше с этой проблемой не сталкивался. так что... но всё равно спасибо за фидбэк)

Comment: `Location is required` где именно у вас файл `loginStage.fxml`? Из того что написано программа ищет его в `src/main/resources/resources/loginStage.fxml`

Comment: похоже на то, действительно, не заметил этого, спасибо )